# need help with 2 sentences

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could somebody paraphrase the last two sentences in a more understandable way for me, and explain the italicized words, please?

One important response to building's negative impact
on the environment is environmental certification. “Green”
buildings are better for the environment as they generally are energy
efficient, water conserving, and use environmentally
friendly building materials. They also seem to have positive
effects for the occupants, for example, “green” buildings are associated
with a high workplace satisfaction and seem to have
psychological and behavioral benefits. Furthermore,
there seems to be a *preference bias* for an indoor environment in
buildings disclosed as environmentally certified. More specifically,
people *assign higher comfort ratings* to an indoor environment if
they are told that the building is environmentally certified,
compared to people who rate the same indoor environment
without that particular information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine 50 people were selected at random, taken inside a building and then asked to rate how comfortable the environment is on a scale of 1 to 10. Say they average a score of 6.3.

Now imagine another group of 50 people were selected at random, taken inside the same building and then had all the environmental features explained to them. They are also asked to rate how comfortable the environment is on a scale of 1 to 10. Say they average a score of 8.8.

The second group are showing a "*preference bias* for an indoor environment in buildings *disclosed* as environmentally certified" compared to the first group.

We deduce this because they have *" assigned higher comfort ratings"* to the same environment than the first group.